# Ajax duplicating results

Tags: jquery, ajax, search

I have online shop website with ajax search which is duplicating some products when I click more results. I couldn't find any errors.

I need help really. Since html output is too long you can check it here http://pastebin.com/Vvu9wLst

```
<?php

// start session
session_start();

// set header
header('content-type: application/json; charset=windows-1250');

// define constants
define("IS_AJAX_REQUEST", (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'));

// include article class
include '../../spraycan/class/Artikl.class.php';

// include mustache.php
include '../../lib/mustache/Mustache.php';
// instantiate mustache engine
$mustache = new Mustache_Engine();

// set template file
if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] != NULL && $_GET['type'] == "small")
    $template_file = "tpl.small.html";
else
    $template_file = "tpl.big.html";
// get template contents
$template = file_get_contents($template_file);

// connect to database
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "opstanak_dgojak", "rtchri92", "opstanak_1");
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

// fetch search query
$s = $_GET['s'];
$s = $mysqli->real_escape_string($s);
// explode search query to words
$words = explode(" ", $s);

// start SELECT
$query = "SELECT * FROM artikli INNER JOIN artikli_group ON artikli.ArtKonto = artikli_group.artGrKonto";
// start WHERE
$where = " WHERE";
$i = 0;

foreach($words as $word)
{
    // set replacements
    $scope = array("š", "đ", "ž","č","ć");
    $replace = array("Š","Đ","Ž","Č","Ć");

    // select first char
    $fc = substr($word,0,1);
    // select other chars
    $oc = substr($word,1);
    // transform first to upper
    $fcb = strtoupper($fc);
    $fcb = str_replace($scope, $replace, $fcb);
    // transform other to upper
    $ocl = strtolower($oc);
    $ocl = str_replace($replace, $scope, $ocl);

    // set normal word
    $word = $fcb.$ocl;
    // set lower word
    $word_lower = strtolower($word);
    $word_lower = str_replace($replace, $scope, $word_lower);
    // set upper word
    $word_upper = strtoupper($word);
    $word_upper = str_replace($scope, $replace, $word_upper);

    if(strlen($word) > 3)
        $word_many = substr($word, 0, -1);
    else
        $word_many = $word;
    // setup where part of query
    if($i == 0)
        $where .= ' (artNaziv LIKE "%'.$word.'%" OR artNaziv LIKE "%'.$word_lower.'%" OR artNaziv LIKE "%'.$word_many.'%" OR artNaziv LIKE "%'.$word_upper.'%")';
    else
        $where .= ' AND (artNaziv LIKE "%'.$word.'%" OR artNaziv LIKE "%'.$word_lower.'%" OR artNaziv LIKE "%'.$word_many.'%" OR artNaziv LIKE "%'.$word_upper.'%")';
    $i++;
}

// update WHERE
if(isset($_GET['since']) && $_GET['since'] != NULL)
    $where .= " AND ID_artikl < ".$_GET['since'];
// set ORDER
$order = " ORDER BY artKn ASC";
// set LIMIT
if($_GET['type'] != "small") {
    $limit = " LIMIT 15";
} else {
    $limit = " LIMIT 5";
}
if($_GET['type'] != "small") {
    // merge SELECT part with the WHERE part for total results count
    $query_num = $query.$where.$order;
    $result_num = $mysqli->query($query_num);
    $total_results_num = $result_num->num_rows;
} else {
    $total_results_num = 0;
}

// merge SELECT part with the WHERE part for fetching results
$query = $query.$where.$order.$limit;

// instantiate response
$response = array('html' => array(), 'after' => '', 'results' => 0, 'total' => $total_results_num, 'first_ID' => "0", 'last_ID' => "0", 'end' => false);


// process query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$response['results'] = $result->num_rows;

if($response['results'] < 15)
{
    $response['end'] = true;
    if($template_file == '')
        $response['after'] = "<div id='load_more' class='not_loading'>Učitaj više rezultata.</div>";
    else
        $response['after'] = "<div id='load_all'>Svi rezultati za pojam <strong>".$s."</strong>.</div>";
}
else
{
    if($template_file == '')
        $response['after'] = "<div id='load_more' class='the_end'>Nema više rezultata.</div>";
    else
        $response['after'] = "<div id='load_all'>Svi rezultati za pojam <strong>".$s."</strong>.</div>";

}

$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if($i == 0)
        $response['first_ID'] = $row['ID_artikl'];
    $row['is_ajax_requested'] = true;
    if($_GET['type'] == 'small')
        $row['artNaziv'] = substr(iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', $row['artNaziv']),0,30).'...';
    else
        $row['artNaziv'] = iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', $row['artNaziv']);
    $row['artInfo'] = iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', $row['artInfo']);
    $row['artGrNaziv'] = iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8', $row['artGrNaziv']);
    array_push($response['html'], $mustache->render($template, new Artikl($row)));
    $response['last_ID'] = $row['ID_artikl'];
    $i++;
}

$pattern = array("\u010d","\u010c","\u009a","\u008a","\u009e","\u008e","\u0111");
$replacement = array("č","Č","š","Š","ž","Ž","đ");

echo str_replace($pattern, $replacement, json_encode($response));

?>
```

Comment: Always post the output HTML of the page too (as saved from your browser) so that we do not have to mentally compile your PHP :)

Comment: Shame it is not all in English, but I gather the `load_poma_results` function is the one we are interested in? At first glance it appears OK. Can you use a tool like Fiddler2 or the Chrome F12 tools to view the server response and see if the duplicates are in the data?

Comment: Sorry I didn't say you all, load_poma_results is for sidebar search, which will be probably removed but i am talking about this search http://www.opstanak.hr/search.php?pojam=D1771
For example when I am searching some item in top of page in header it works normally but when i click _Nema više rezultata_ which means No more results, some items duplicate but some not.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the reputation to comment, but a couple of things regarding security:

1) You have just publicly posted your database username and password. If your server was ever compromised, this kind of information would grant access to an attacker to do immediate and severe damage.

2) Speaking of security and server compromise, Do not use session_start() by itself, as it is not secure. I recommend you perform secure session management. See [this link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet) for information, and [this link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions) for some examples. (Make sure you read the comments section in the last link for more info)